# Postgresql - How update another table after update one with specific data

Tags: database, postgresql

I have 2 tables,

```
CREATE TABLE B(
offer_id serial primary key,
number_of_placement int,
constraint num_of_placement_chk check (number_of_placement >0)
);

create table a (
id serial,
offer_id int references b(offer_id),//refer to table b offer_id
status varchar(20) default 'PENDING');
```

and my function and trigger,

```
Create or replace function update_no_offer_placement_func() 
returns trigger as $body$
begin
    if(new.status == 'ACCEPTED') then // if the status is update with 'ACCEPTED' value
        update b set number_of_placement = number_of_placement -1; //reduce the number of placement by 1
    end if;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_no_offer_placement_trig //after update table a
     AFTER update ON a
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_no_offer_placement_func();
```

I would like to update table b's number of placement so tht it reduces its number by 1 if only the value updated in a is 'ACCEPTED'. How should i do that?
I tried but its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_no_offer_placement_func()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE B SET number_of_placement = number_of_placement -1 FROM a WHERE B.offer_id = a.offer_id AND a.status = 'ACCEPTED';
RETURN NULL;  -- AFTER trigger can return NULL
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER update_no_offer_placement_trig 
AFTER update ON a
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_no_offer_placement_func();
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT @Monty!!!! 1 MORE QUESTION, if wanna like after there's a acceptance, other status will turn 'REJECTED', do i jsut add
`UPDATE A SET STATUS = 'REJECTED' WHERE ID <> OLD.ID;`??

Comment: do you want another trigger for this ? When this trigger will call ?

Comment: oh it's ok.. i just add few things and its done. this is what i added
`IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
  IF NEW.status = 'ACCEPTED' THEN
   UPDATE offer SET rem_num_count = rem_num_count - 1 FROM response WHERE response.offer_id = offer.offer_id AND response.status = 'ACCEPTED';
   update response set status = 'REJECTED' WHERE student_id = old.student_id 
   and offer_id <> old.offer_id;
  END IF;
 END IF;`